# Error on the format

Tags: c

`11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’`
This is my error....Cant fix it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char *a;
char *count;
char str[100];
int i ;
printf("\n:enter string for Palindrome test\t");
scanf("%s", &str);
i= strlen(str);
//a=(char *)malloc(i*sizeof(char));
a=&str[0];
count=&str[i-1];
while((*(a++)==*(count--)) && i>=1)
{ i--; }
if(i==0) { printf("\n%s is a palin",str);}
else { printf("\n%s is not palin",str);}

}
```

Comment: And why my code does not run????

Comment: It is running well. See it [here](http://ideone.com/ZxZQEE). Just add `return 0;` before the closing `}` for `main`.

Comment: Do not believe you can declare a single symbol as a palindrome …

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can fix it.  Just don't pass the wrong type.  Change:

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

To:

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

Or, equivalently:

```
scanf("%s", &str[0]);
```

Comment: Dunno - what does your debugger say?

Answer (score 0):

You don't always use an ampersand passing arguments to scanf(). If the format string contains either a %c or a %s, it will be looking for a char* type. When you call it with &str, you are calling it with a char** type, or as the compiler says, a char*[100] (a pointer to an array of 100 chars).

Comment: `char **` and `char (*)[100]` are not the same type.